# Создание потоков в процессе powershell

Tags: windows, многопоточность, powershell, процесс

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как в powershell создать процесс, а в нем - два потока? Первый поток вызывает утилиту на компе, второй - убивает первый поток спустя 20 секунд после начала работы первого потока?

Answer (score 0):

Не усложняйте (с) Оккам :)

Формально, powershell не поддерживает многопоточность, хотя некоторое подобие можно организовать через jobs, если желаете, - читайте [Запуск заданий на основе потоков и управление ими](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs?view=powershell-7.3)

Но подобную вещь гораздо проще организовать, на мой вкус, через запуск двух скриптов со сторонним контролем времени: первый, а затем, через 20 секунд - второй. И не нужно работать с костылями.